# I want to schedule a background task that runs every minute and check a condition until condition is True in Android

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager

I am designing a birthday based Android app. This app check current system date, if date is birth date, app will start a music and allow other activities. Else, the app will give an error message to wait until birth date and exit.

Below is the sample code:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date dateobj = new Date();
        Date date1 = sdf.parse(sdf.format(dateobj));
        Date date2 = sdf.parse("2016-05-30");
        if (date1.compareTo(date2) >= 0) {
// Start a music
//Other task
}
else
{ 
// You need to wait message 
}
```

Now, I want this condition to be checked after every 60 seconds (1 minute) automatically, **even if app is not open** [Probably alarmManager might help, but I am not sure how] , something like a background task. This task should be repeated until condition is true.

If user opens the app before the birth date, an error alert is displayed and app is closed.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the AlarmManager setRepeating function to achieve that. Check this link for details - https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html

As for your requirement of running the code even when it is not open, you should make use of BroadcastReceiver. You need to pass your BroadcastReceiver as a PendingIntent to the AlarmManager.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer this. I went through the given link and multiple other sites before asking the question here, However I wasn't able to get this to work as expected.